# Unable to connect to network

Tags: networking, 22.04, internet, dns

For some reason I cannot access anything other than local sites hosted on my network - I do connect to the router however the WiFi icon appears as a ? rather than showing me the signal strength.

Aswell as this, I'm unable to get data from any site that isn't on my network - failing on a DNS check.

I have confirmed it's not an issue with the wireless connectivity of my router, as connecting via Ethernet doesn't work, aswell as using USB tethering from my phone and a regular mobile hotspot don't work. Every other device on my network works perfectly with the router.

Is there any other reason that my machine can't access the internet or would I have to re-install the OS and hope it doesn't happen in the future?

`dig` output:

```
$ dig example.com
;; communications error to ::1#53: connection refused
;; communications error to ::1#53: connection refused
;; communications error to ::1#53: connection refused
;; communications error to 127.0.0.1#53: connection refused

; <<>> DiG 9.18.18-0ubuntu0.22.04.1-Ubuntu <<>> example.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; no servers could be reached

$ dig @8.8.8.8 example.com

; <<>> DiG 9.18.18-0ubuntu0.22.04.1-Ubuntu <<>> @8.8.8.8 example.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY; status: NO ERROR, id: 48924
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.             IN        A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.        15478 IN        A      93.184.216.34

;; Query time: 111 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Tue Feb 20 18:47:38 GMT 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 56
```

Comment: Please [edit] with `dig example.com` and `dig @8.8.8.8 example.com`

Comment: @DanielT done that - however that brings the question of why it's not automatically finding the DNS server even when it's automatic. I changed the DNS in WiFi settings however it still doesn't work.

Comment: The systemd-resolved DNS caching server at 127.0.0.53 should already be finding the right upstream DNS server, but the `/etc/resolv.conf` is pointing to the wrong local IP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `/etc/resolv.conf` is broken. It should not connect to `127.0.0.1#53` but rather `127.0.0.53#53`. Let's fix it:

1. `sudo systemctl enable systemd-resolved`
2. `sudo systemctl start systemd-resolved`
3. `sudo unlink /etc/resolv.conf`
4. `sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf`
5. Verify that it contains "nameserver 127.0.0.53". If not, reboot to regenerate it